# Take filename as input from user and split its name and rename it

Tags: vba, split, rename

```
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename()

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Select the File"
    Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Please Select the File"
End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Conversion = CStr(FileToOpen)
Result = Split(Conversion, ".")
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: You could use [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object).